# Parse PHP variable in html template

Tags: php, html, templates

I know it has been discussed many times, but I can not find any solution to this problem.

I have a PHP file with the following code

```
if (file_exists("email.html")) {
        $message = file_get_contents("email.html");
    } else {
        echo "No email.html file present";
        return;
    }
```

in my file email.html I have something like:

```
  <p>Hello %recipient.UserName%, you receive this Email because you signed up at our site.</p>
```

variable $UserName is declared in the php file (in array).

When looking at the html file output, I see the variable is not correctly passed and stays as % %

Any suggestion?
thanks!

Comment: change this to <?php echo %recipient.UserName%; ?>

Comment: `file_get_contents()` just gets the contents, it does not parse anything so if you don't do that yourself after getting it, it will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a template engine you can't do it with `% %` OR other symbol . for your question simple approach is to use it like this :

```
  <p>Hello <? = $recipient['UserName'] ?>, you receive this Email because you signed up at our site.</p>
```

**EDIT**

you have to include the file

```
ob_start();
include "email.html";
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Yes right a forgot about this i will edit my answer thanks